# Source map does not resolve variables while debugging CRA app

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, create-react-app, source-maps

Recently, I've tried to debug my CRA app and it occurred that variables are not resolved using source maps. The code is resolved but not variables. I tried in Chrome as well as in WebStorm (running in Chrome), same result.

[image]

You may see that the `time` is not defined while in fact in this context it's `d`. Do you think it's related to a browser?

Comment: Similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74974508/cannot-see-my-variables-in-console-while-debuging-react-app-on-production. The same happens to me, no idea about the cause or possible solution