# Cannot see my variables in console while debuging react app on production

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, debugging, microsoft-edge

I am new to the react world and trying to use it in my sharepoint environment. I am packaging the app for production with source maps and upload it to the sharepoint site that I will use it in. App runs without a problem in the sharepoint but in the developer toolbox I cannot debug it completely. I can see my js file, put the debug point, and it pauses on the point but I cannot see the variables in console as you can see in the screenshot below.

[image]

But if I try the same code in dev environment with npm start I can see the same variable in console without any problem.

Is this normal behavior or am I doing something wrong? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you using Vercel or something? Maybe you can give us a minimal code sample to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Nope nothing fancy in the code. Just a button click event handler and inside that handler I only got let abc = 0; console.log(abc); This code can output the value of abc variable (which is 0) on the console but if I put a breakpoint and try to call the abc on console it gives error. Also because of publishing it to SharePoint site I got homepage attribute set to my SharePoint site url in package.json

Comment: Well, I've noticed that you actually have `abcdef` in the console. Did you type that? The variable can be printed when you click the button, but won't be recognized when you manually type the variable name in the console.

Comment: @KendrickLi this is the whole question. Normally when you add a breakpoint somewhere you can access local variables in that scope, but here it doesn't work

Comment: @Konrad yes exactly you summarized it perfectly thanks, console log can write the value on the console but I cannot access it in console manually.

Comment: I forgot the breakpoint feature and thanks @Konrad for explaining that. Now I can successfully reproduce the issue in production (static server), but I haven't figured out why. Looking for someone with a better idea.

Comment: @KendrickLi If you can reproduce this, I guess this is not a specific problem just for me and I am not doing some thing wrong. But it is a general problem or design choice may be.

Comment: @MustafaYılmaz Yes, exactly. You will have the same result in Chrome and Firefox, so it should be a common behavior (or issue) in React.

Comment: Is this an issue (bug, problem, etc) or design choice? Do you know anything about it @KendrickLi?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue with a React app created with Create React App. In the same codebase we have JavaScript files from a different project where breakpoints behave as expected, but inside the React app the variables are all undefined. I suspect it could come from the sourcemaps configuration but not really sure.

Comment: Similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73686691/source-map-does-not-resolve-variables-while-debugging-cra-app